# Trouble with java xml transformer while using inside Spring WS interceptor

Tags: java, xml, web-services, spring

Hi I am writing a SAOP web service using Spring which has a complex type embedded inside the header.

```
 <soapenv:Header>
      <ser:Header>
           <ser:from>xyz</ser:from>
           <ser:to>abc</ser:to>
      </ser:Header>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
     <abc>test</abc>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

At my endpoint, I wrote the implementation for generating SOAP body. I also implemented a Response interceptor in Spring to generate SOAP Header in the required format

```
StringBuffer headerXml = new StringBuffer();
headerXml.append("<ser:Header xmlns:mos=\"http://test.services.com\">")
.append("<ser:from>xyz</ser:from>");
.append("<ser:to>abc</ser:to>");
.append("</ser:Header>");
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(headerXml.toString()));
Result xmlOutput = soapHeader.getResult();
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
try{
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", String.valueOf(4));
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);     
}catch(IllegalArgumentException ie){
    ie.printStackTrace();
}catch(TransformerException te){
    te.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here I am getting Result object from SoapHeader and trying to update it with the String parsed to xml using transformer

```
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
```

But here, I am getting only the first line into Ouput header as follows

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <ser:Header xmlns:ser="http://test.services.com"/>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I am not getting full header. Although in deebug mode I can see that the whole string header was added into **xmlInput** variable

I tried all the options but was unsuccessful. Please help in this regard as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What happens if you remove the .append("<ser:Header>"); line?

Comment: Davos555..Sorry my mistake. That line of code was not there. I edited the query!